# PhoneGap Build can't see plugins

Tags: android, eclipse, cordova, phonegap-plugins, phonegap-build

I have a PhoneGap Android application in Eclipse. I have using PhoneGap version: 3.5.0-0.21.14.

It use two plugins: Device and BarcodeScanner.
Here are the config.xml entries.

```
<feature name="Device">
    <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.device.Device" />
</feature>
<feature name="BarcodeScanner">
    <param name="android-package" value="com.phonegap.plugins.barcodescanner.BarcodeScanner" />
</feature>
```

When running from Eclipse it works with no problem.  I then upload to 'PhoneGap Build' and it will not work - even for the Android build (I have only tested the Android build so far).

LogCat shows the following errors:

```
Exec() call to unknown plugin: Device
Exec() call to unknown plugin: barcodescanner
```

I have tried versions of the build with only one of these plugins and still get the error for that plugin

Here is how I prepare the phoneGap build.

1. Copy the assets/www folder.
2. In the copy, I remove cordova.js.
3. Copy /res/xml/config.xml to the www folder (at the same level with index.html).
4. Zip this www copy.
5. Upload to PhoneGap Build and Build.

Why can phoneGap Build not see these plugins when they work fine in my local environment?

The plugins also add "uses-permission" entries to the Android manifest.xml file.  How do I get these values to PhoneGap Build?  Does that come by adding the feature tags to config.xml (see above)?

Answer (score 0):

You can only use plugins in Build that work with Build. Not all PG plugins work with PGB.

You need to read the PGB documentation.

An example is that AdMob plugin for PG. There is no such plugin for PGB.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the feature tag is platform specific.  I had to add these plugin tags also:

```
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.device"  />
<gap:plugin name="com.phonegap.plugins.barcodescanner"  />
```

Also, my default config did not have the gap namespace.  I did have a cdv Cordova namespace but that didn't work.  I had to add gap (in addition to Cordova).

```
xmlns:gap   = "http://phonegap.com/ns/1.0"
```

I added the plugin tags in addition to the feature tags that I already had.

I believe that phone gap build needs the generic plugin and will find the appropriate plugin when building.  This is not clear from the documentation.